# How to remove footer from checkout onepage

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, layout, onepage-checkout

I want to removed the footer from the onepage checkout in magento. I am try coding  using module controller and modulename and action on condition.

Can any one tell me a good process for changing layout in the checkout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a local.xml file with the following code snippet so you do not have to change the core layout.xml files.

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <remove name="footer"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 2):

At last i have a good process to remove footer from checkout onepage.I have remove footer changing in checkout.xml.

```
  <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="left"/>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">....
....
 <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
<remove name="footer" />
  </checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: Hopefully this checkout.xml is in your own theme! If not, you should use Davids method, because it makes the update easier.

Comment: ya,Fabian is right